# disable all selectbox onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is how i disable all submit button on click

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    // On submit disable its submit button
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

how to `disable all selectbox onchange easily` for all selectbox in the page

Comment: could you please make your question a little clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will disable all select boxes:

```
$('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To tie it to a form submission you can add it to your existing function.

To bind this to a select box's onChange event you can use [jQuery's change listener](http://api.jquery.com/change/).  So if you want all select boxes disabled when any select box changes you can use this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

If you want to operate on a specific select box you can change the first `$('select')` above to reference *that* box.

Comment: but i only want to disable all selectboxes when "selectbox onchange" event is called

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as what you're doing above, just change it to select

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    // On submit disable its submit button
    $('select', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: but i only want to disable all selectboxes when "selectbox onchange" event is called

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you want to disable it as soon as someone changes a value inside the select?